# Nginx rewrite url args

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress website and a I need rewrite:

> myurl.com/name-of-my-post/?lang=**es**

To

> myurl.com/**es**/name-of-my-post/

I allready try everthing that i can found but not is working

P.S  I don't need send the lang parameter to index.php becausa there is a plugin that reply to

> myurl.com/**es**/name-of-my-post/ but not rewrite when a visit come from myurl.com/name-of-my-post/?lang=**es**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix (which may not work because it is *too* simple) is to permanently redirect any URI with a `lang` parameter:

```
if ($arg_lang) {
    return 301 /$arg_lang$uri;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive.